# Ganglia web generating "error collecting ganglia data (:): fsockopen error"

Tags: redhat, rhel5, ganglia

Now, I'm trying to install a new ganglia-web interface to replace an older one. Google searching on the error got me a lot, but none of it helps. One large distinction I note is that Google usually returns "`There was an error collecting ganglia data (127.0.0.1:8642): fsockopen error:`" where my error does not include an IP address or port number.

[The only substantive result that matches my error](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.monitoring.ganglia.general/1521) says I should check conf.php, but that file isn't anywhere obvious.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feh.

Turns out to have been a bad install. When yum thinks the package is installed, but "`/usr/sbin/gmetad`" doesn't actually exist, that's a clue...

Reinstalled, and I'm good.